# How to resolve this github/heroku conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have an app on Heroku that I have had for a couple of years, but now I need to refactor some code and update some gems.

When I first started the app I was on a totally different machine. So I had to clone the github repo for that app.

Now I want to push the first changes but I get this error:

```
set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/alfa-blog.git
```

I thought it was asking me to do something like this:

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/alfa-blog.git
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal: remote heroku already exists.
```

How do I resolve this? If there is anything unclear, please let me know so I may clarify.

Do I delete the origin one?

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/alfa-blog.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/alfa-blog.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/<github-page>/Alpha_Blog.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<github-page>/Alpha_Blog.git (push)
```

Trying to rename remote repo:

```
$ git remote rename https://git.heroku.com/alfa-blog.git https://github.com/ldco2016/Alpha_Blog.git
fatal: No such remote: https://git.heroku.com/alfa-blog.git
```

Comment: @SebastianPalma, do I delete the heroku one? I added the output of the ```git remote -v``` above.

Comment: I  am having problems renaming the remote. I will post what I am getting above.

Comment: when I do that I get, ```fatal: No such remote: alfa-blog``` from doing ```$ git remote rename alfa-blog Alpha_Blog```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove or rename anything, just `set-url` to the repo you are currently working in, like this:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<github-page>Alpha_Blog.git
```

Then you should be able to push your new changes to your existing app on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Is the remote set to a different url right now? You could try removing it and then adding as you tried again.